# MySQL takes toomuch time to display 1 million data

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I'm working on an application with has millions of data, and I need to list all the data in a page. At first I was fetching all the data in a single query and the pagination was done in the `client side`. But that takes almost 15 minutes to load the complete set. So I changed the code for fetching 10 rows per request and the pagination was done on `server side`. But still the performance is not up to the mark. So what all things should do to get the data quickly or what is the best way to handle huge data.

My query to fetch data :

**UPDATED** :

```
SELECT  w.work_order_id,
(SELECT CONCAT(user_fname, ' ', user_lname) FROM users WHERE user_id = w.created_by) AS created_by, 
CASE w.assignee WHEN 0 THEN  'All' WHEN -1 THEN 'Unassigned' ELSE CONCAT(u.user_fname, ' ', u.user_lname) END AS assignee 
FROM FiveVan_work_orders w 
LEFT JOIN users u ON (u.user_id = w.assignee) 
WHERE ( w.work_order_status != 'Deleted' && w.work_order_status != 'Closed') ORDER BY w.created_on DESC LIMIT 0,10;
```

I have created index for the pages and this is the result of explaining the query

```
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys     | key           | key_len | ref                           | rows   | Extra                                    |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | w     | index  | work_order_status | work_order_id | 790     | NULL                          | 340319 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY       | 4       | fivevan_loadtest.w.assignee   |      1 | NULL                                     |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | users | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY       | 4       | fivevan_loadtest.w.created_by |      1 | NULL                                     |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You could split up the data into separate tables with joining IDs, so the data being queried is far less.. and the other parts of each record are pulled in after the first lot.

Comment: I don't see and LIMIT x,y... so your query is still getting ALL the data instead of only parts of it

and subselects on large data will always be slow

Comment: @Max Sorry, My bad. This was the query used before.

Comment: can u post ur current query plz?

Comment: @Max I have added limit

Comment: You can add an index on theses two fields: w.assignee AND w.work_order_status. And create an other INNER JOIN on users to get your CONCAT(user_fname, ' ', user_lname), it will be better.

Comment: I would try to get rid of that dependent subquery. Join a second time with the user table, but on `w.created_by = u2.user_id` and see if it gets better.  (This would save you 1 Million querys, since it's a correlated query)

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE  ( w.work_order_status != 'Deleted' &&
         w.work_order_status != 'Closed')
ORDER BY  w.created_on DESC
```

If there is *only* one more value of `work_order_status`, then change that to

```
WHERE w.work_order_status = 'Open'
ORDER BY w.created_on DESC
```

and add

```
INDEX(work_order_status, created_on)
```

If there are multiple other values, the this may work (less well):

```
INDEX(created_on)
```

To get even better performance, you need to "remember where you left off" instead of using `OFFSET`.  I discuss that in [my pagination blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).